# Building String Of Rows, Then Cut to WorkSheet in Same Workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I'm getting Method 'Range' of object'_Global'failed in the below line of the below code.

```
Dim myRange As String

    For c = 7 To ioFileLastRow Step 1
       If Left(ioFilePreEx.Cells(c, 21), 4) <> "DIVD" Then
        myRange = myRange & "," & c & ":" & c
       End If
       Next c

    Range(Left(myRange, Len(myRange) - 1)).Cut Destination:=ioFilePreEx1.Range("A" & ioFileLastRow).End(xlUp).Offset(1) 'Error Occurs Here
       End Sub
```

Please help.
Thanks!

Comment: How long do you think myrange is? What happens if it's length is zero? But your immediate error is probably at the end of your line .Offset(1) should be .Offset(1,0)

Comment: myRange is 215 lines in the format ",7:7, 11:11, 12:12, 13:13..."

Comment: Now I'm thinking myRange is infinite so I'll give a "do until" loop a try so that myRange is finite using the vbNullString built in function. I'll let you know the outcome. Thanks!

Comment: that did the trick! Final code:

Comment: Dim myRange As String
c = 7
    Do Until ioFilePreEx.Cells(c, 1).Value = vbNullString
        If ioFilePreEx.Cells(c, 21) <> "DIVD" Then
        myRange = myRange & "," & c & ":" & c
        End If
    c = c + 1
Loop
ioFilePreEx.Range(Mid(myRange, 2)).Copy Destination:=ioFilePreEx1.Range("A" & ioFileLastRow).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
ioFilePreEx.Range(Mid(myRange, 2)).Delete

Comment: false alarm. The code in the answer doesn't work on a larger data set as I'm still receiving the same error.

Comment: I am exceeding the maximum length of characters a string can hold, that is why the code doesn't work for larger sets.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim myRange As String
c = 7
Do Until ioFilePreEx.Cells(c, 1).Value = vbNullString
If ioFilePreEx.Cells(c, 21) <> "DIVD" Then
myRange = myRange & "," & c & ":" & c
End If
c = c + 1
Loop
ioFilePreEx.Range(Mid(myRange, 2)).Copy Destination:=ioFilePreEx1.Range("A" 
& ioFileLastRow).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
ioFilePreEx.Range(Mid(myRange, 2)).Delete

End Sub
```